# mongodb grouping repetetive documents to one array

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to get all the documents of a specific key organised into an array. I don't want to get the same key element again and again if any other parameter is different.
Sample Document:-

```
{
    name:"sweta",
    age:23
    address:india,
    hobby:singing
},
{
    name:"john",
    age:24
    address:germany,
    hobby:singing
},
{
    name:"peter",
    age:24
    address:india,
    hobby:dancing
},
{
    name:"marry",
    age:23
    address:india,
    hobby:singing
},
```

what i have tried?

```
return db.aggregate([
 {
       $match:{age:23}
 },
 {
       "$group":{
           "_id": {"age":"$age"},
        }
 },
 {   
       "$group":{
           "_id":"$_id.age",
           "name":{ $first: "$_id.name"},
           "address":{ $first: "$_id.address"},
           "hobby":{ $first: "$_id.hobby"},
  }
])
```

Basically grouping in this format reduces the maximum business logic.

Expected Answer =

```
  [
      {
        "23":[
                {name:"sweta",address:india,hobby:singing},
                {name:"marry",address:india,hobby:singing},
             ]
       },
       {
          "24":[
                {name:"john",address:germany,hobby:singing},
                {name:"peter",address:france,hobby:singing}
             ]
         }

 ]
```

Anyone any idea how to get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this

```
db.getCollection('Test').aggregate([
{ $group: { _id: "$age" , 
    data: { $push: {"name":"$name", "address":"$address", "hobby":"$hobby"}},    
    }
},
{ "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": { 
      "$arrayToObject": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          [
            { "k": {$toString: "$_id"}, "v": "$data"  }
          ]
        ]
      } 
    }
  }}
])
```

Result:

```
[ {
    "24" : [ 
        { "name" : "john", "address" : "germany", "hobby" : "singing" }, 
        { "name" : "peter", "address" : "india", "hobby" : "dancing" }
    ]
},
{
    "23" : [ 
        { "name" : "sweta", "address" : "india", "hobby" : "singing" }, 
        { "name" : "marry", "address" : "india", "hobby" : "singing" }
    ]
}]
```